# Webdriver.io - Selenium standalone jar is giving error missing chrome dependencies

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, npm, webdriver-io

I am new to webdriver.io world, I have selenium standalone version:6.18.0 installed on my package.json.

But when I am trying to start selenium standalone server by running below command I am getting below error

```
**varhe@LAPTOP-KVK0SFU4 MINGW64 /c/Projects/WebdriverioFramework
$ ./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone start
C:\Projects\WebdriverioFramework\node_modules\selenium-standalone\bin\selenium-standalone:87
        throw err;
        ^
Error: Missing C:\Projects\WebdriverioFramework\node_modules\selenium-standalone\.selenium\chromedriver\83.0.4103.39-x64-chromedriver
    at C:\Projects\WebdriverioFramework\node_modules\selenium-standalone\lib\check-paths-existence.js:15:20
    at suppressedCallback (fs.js:215:5)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:156:23)**

**
```

I have searched online and tried multiple option to resolve this issue but still no luck.
Could you look into this and help to resolve it

Comment: Please add your package.json and config details after removing sensitive data if you can.

Comment: Do you get any resolution for this? I am facing the same issue.